# Converting any type to any type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-conversion

I want to have a function template to make arbitrary type conversions possible:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
S Convert(const T& input)
{
  // code.....
}
```

For example:

```
Convert<int, std::string>(12); // convert int to std::string
Convert<std::string, CString>("test"); // convert std::string to CString
Convert<bool, int>(true); // convert bool to int
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. `boost::lexical_cast` does that, albeit not for `CString`, but there are certainly customisation points.

Comment: @Quentin i don't want to use the boost

Comment: That's your call, but it means that yes, it is possible, and you could take inspiration from Boost's source code if you want to write your own.

Comment: @Quentin ok, tanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you want. What is `Convert` supposed to *mean*? For some types, there are multiple ways to convert from `T` to `S` that may all be useful in different contexts. This is why C++ has many different cast operators with different semantics, and why formatting an integer as a string can be done in many different ways with different configuration options. If the question is just, can I make a template function with arbitrary semantics and special cases of behavior, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @ChrisBeck I want supported bool, string, CString, int, double, this conversion

Comment: There are no really arbitrary type conversions in C++, of course. You cannot turn `struct S {};` into an `int`. It seems you just have a set of specific conversions needed in your program, and you are looking for a way to unify the conversion syntax with templates.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yes, I know and  i agree, and i want Help me for unify the conversion syntax with templates.....

Answer (score 2):

You could start with the following primary function template:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
S Convert(const T& input) {
    return static_cast<S>(input);
}
```

This will work for converting `bool` to `int`. However, for other, more elaborated conversions, you need to fully specialize that template for the types being involved. It's you the one who has to define the semantics of the corresponding conversions.

For example, a specialization for converting `int` to `std::string` could be:

```
template<>
std::string Convert<int, std::string>(const int& input) {
    return std::to_string(input);
}
```

and the specialization for converting `std::string` to `CString` could be:

```
template<>
CString Convert<std::string, CString>(const std::string& input) {
   return CString(input.c_str());
}
```

---

#### Follow-up implementation

For safer functions consider the definitions above instead (read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811867/converting-any-type-to-any-type/48811987?noredirect=1#comment84632068_48811987)). Note that order of the template parameters are swapped regarding OP's question.

```
// (0) primary function template
template<typename TDst, typename TSrc>
TDst Convert(const TSrc& input) {
    return static_cast<TDst>(input);
}

// (1) specialization for converting int to string
template<>
std::string Convert<std::string, int>(const int& input) {
    return std::to_string(input);
}

// (2) overload for necessary std::string
template<typename TDst = CString>
TDst Convert(std::string& str) {
    return str.c_str();
}

// (3) overload for literal strings
template<typename TDst = CString>
TDst Convert(const char *cstr) {
    return cstr;
}
```

That way:

```
Convert<int>(true); // (0)

Convert<std::string>(12); // (1)

std::string str("foo");
Convert<CString>(str); // (2)

Convert<CString>("foo"); // (3)

Convert<CString, std::string>("foo"); // <-- compile error
```

Comment: static_cast cann't convert std::string to CString

Comment: @JackD you have to provide a specialization for converting a `std::string` into a `CString`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: this `std::string` to `CString` function seems somewhat unsafe, at least for my tastes, it seems very easy to create an invalid pointer: `const char * ptr = Convert<std::string, Cstring>("foobar"); // Ouch` if you are actually going to use it you might want to make it so that the type `T` is second template parameter, not first, and is always deduced from context rather than specified explicitly

Comment: @ChrisBeck Sorry, I don't see the point. If `CString` does implicitly convert to `const char *`, then we can still do `const char * ptr = Convert<std::string, CString>(str);` (being `str` a `std::string` object) and the same problem arises. I would say that the actual issue is that `CString` converts to a pointer to the string contained in the object that is about to be destroyed. What I am missing?

Comment: What I would want would be something like (1) I write in my code `Convert<Cstring>("foobar")` instead (2) The compiler deduces this as `Convert<Cstring, Cstring>("foobar")`, and it compiles to a no-op function call, which is safe since we just return pointer to string literal. There's no `std::string` involved when there doesn't need to be (3) if someone specifies both template parameters explicitly, rather than letting the compiler deduce the input type e.g. `Convert<std::string,CString>("foobar")`, it's considered a bug and caught easily

Comment: @ChrisBeck Thanks for the detailed explanation. I've expanded the answer accordingly.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 This is not what I wanted, I want just one function. but I get to idea from this samples, thank you a lot...